# Why does my image does not show up on my Template

Tags: python, django, postgresql, image, templates

My Goal is that the user can upload a new Manga Cover Image and the title of the Manga. I would like to show the image on the Template but it says in my command line.

```
Not Found: /media/onepiece.jpg
```

In my Postgressql it is added. The only thing I see is a File with a white cloud and a green hill. I also installed Pillow. My media folder contains the subfolder *images* and it is empty. I am really confused because the error message is looking up in the *media folder* but not 1 level deeper to *images*.

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media').replace('\\', '/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**App**

*models.py*

```
class Manga(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)
    title = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)
```

*views.py*

```
def manga_post(request):
    manga_img = request.POST.get('manga_img')
    manga_title = request.POST.get('manga_title')

    manga_conf= Manga.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
    manga_conf.img = manga_img
    manga_conf.title = manga_title

    manga_settings.save()
    return redirect('settings_manga')
```

*template (Where the post hapening)*

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="{% url 'post_manga' %}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {% if manga.img %}
                    <img src="{{ manga.img.url }}" alt="Add Manga Picture">
                {% else %}
                    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/43/43254.png"
                         alt="" class="manga-img">
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="manga-image-input" name="manga_img">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="imageGroup" id="img-label">Choose Image</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

I searched much on the web. And I seen many SO Post about people who whether forget to add the static to the urlspatterns or on the App level. This does not help me by this problem.

*urls.py from Project*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('mangas/', include('manga.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

*urls.py from the app*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.mangas, name='mangas'),
    path('post', views.post_manga, name='post_manga'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Hopefully you can help me if I need to edit something please notice me. I am really struggling.

Best Regards
Markus

Comment: hello, is "DEBUG=True"  in your settings?

Comment: @engin_ipek yes